# NodeJs - mongoose function always return null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I am new to nodeJs and i am trying to return apikey from the function saveApi but it always returns null. Can you help me with that?

```
   var saveApi =  async (email) => {
    const apikeyvalue = apigen.create().apiKey;
    console.log("key",apikeyvalue)
    const apikey = require("../models/api");
    var finalkey=null
    try {
        let key = new apikey({ email: email, apikey: apikeyvalue })
        finalkey = await key.save();
      } catch (e) {
        throw new ProductCreateError();
      }
      return finalkey.apikey
};
```

Here is the definition of my apikey model

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var apiSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    apikey:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model(
    'apikey', apiSchema, 'apikeys');
```

and here is the function call to saveApi()

```
var api = saveApi.then(obj.username)
```

Comment: Here is the function call.  var api = saveApi.then(obj.username)

Comment: Share the definition of `apikey`, or at least the definition of `key.save()`